# how to select emailadress or www link with doubleclick in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard

how to select and copy an emailadress or www link by doubleclick at once into clipboard with autohotkey? eg mailadress in a text part of any program.

Thanks for any advice
Andreas

Comment: Where is the www link or mail address stored? Where do you want to extract it from and how? Hotkey, mouse? Please add more info.

Answer (score 0):

it is stored in a RTF file which is displayed by the richedit gui. but in the meantime i solved the problem in a different way with dedicated messagehandler recognizing the links itself ...

br andreas